# rabbitmq send data php in linux

Tags: php, centos, rabbitmq

i try to send data to rabbitmq-server, but it keep returning error :

"A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: Channel/AMQPChannel.php

Line Number: 1098"

here's my code :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

 function send_log($id, $id_user, $object_id){
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
    $msg = '';
    if ($id == 24 || $id == 7){
        $msg = new AMQPMessage(json_encode(array('id' => 2, 'id_user' => $id_user, 'id_post' => $object_id)));
    }elseif($id == 6){
        $msg = new AMQPMessage(json_encode(array('id' => 3, 'id_user' => $id_user, 'id_post' => $object_id)));
    }
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
    //echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
}
```

i dont know why it keep returning that error. because before i was trying the same code in windows OS and its fine. now im using centos then turn like that...
please help me if you know the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that php script doesn't work for my server. my best guess is about php version in my server. so, i make another script with python to send data to rabbit server. and it works.